# how to read these json files

Tags: python, json, pandas

My data folder has lots of json files of amazon product info, ratings, reviews and etc. Each json file contains info about one particular amazon product. I'm stuck in the first step of my project: loading data. 
I tried:
json module:   json.loads(...)

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

then I tried:
pandas json reader:   pd.read_json(...)

```
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

Anyone please kindly help me with this. Thank you so much!

Below is one of the file content:

{"Reviews": [], "ProductInfo": {"Price": "$1,039.95", "Features": "KIT INCLUDES 15 PRODUCTS -- All BRAND NEW Items with all Manufacturer-supplied Accessories + Full USA Warranties:\n<1> Nikon D5200 Digital SLR Camera & 18-55mm G VR DX AF-S Zoom Lens (Red) + <2> Nikon 55-200mm VR DX AF-S Lens + <3> Samyang 500mm Telephoto Lens +\n<4> Transcend 32GB Class10 SD Card + <5> Vivitar 52mm UV Glass Filter + <6> Additional Vivitar 52mm UV Glass Filter + <7> ML-L3 Shutter Remote Control +\n<8> Rokinon 67\" Monopod & Case + <9> PD Laptop/Tablet DSLR Backpack + <10> PD 2.5x Tele & .45x Wide Lens + <11> PD 6pc Complete Cleaning Kit +\n<12> PD Memory Card Storage Wallet + <13> LCD Monitor Screen Protectors + <14> T Mount for Nikon + <15> Instruction Sheet for T-Mount", "Name": "Nikon D5200 Digital SLR Camera & 18-55mm G VR DX AF-S Zoom Lens (Red) with 55-200mm VR + 500mm Telephoto Lens + 32GB Card + Backpack + Tele/Wide Lenses + Monopod + Accessory Kit", "ImgURL": "[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61wRao9FbdL.*SY300*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61wRao9FbdL._SY300_.jpg)", "ProductID": "B00B4EKX8A"}}%

Comment: Why do you have a % sign at the end?

Comment: i don't know. Those are the files I got. @oshaiken

Comment: Show your full exact code.

Comment: Just like Yash posted.

Comment: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:
   data_string = data_file.read()    
   try:
       data = json.loads(data_string)
       print('Success!')
   except ValueError:
       print('Failed:')
       print(repr(data_string))
```

If it fails, show us the output.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get(url, timeout=1000)
data = json.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is in files, then all you need to do is load it in and then read the correct keys from it.

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
   data = json.load(data_file)
```

you should then be able to access keys like

`data["productInfor"]["Price"]`

Also not sure why your JSON has a % at the end of it but it shouldn't because that is an incorrect format and you won't be able to load it in without an error.

Try running without the % at the end of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove % sign from the input json